# RFC 5424 Syslog Viewer

Tags: log-files, syslog

I've been looking for a log viewer that understands syslog messages, specifically in RFC 5424 format (including structured data elements), and ideally allows live monitoring (`tail` like) and filtering/searching.

The viewers and analysis tools I've tried either seem to not understand the protocol, or they swallow or ignore structured data elements.

LogAnalyzer for example seems to understand the basic syslog syntax and decodes severity and facility properly, but it's database format does not include structured data.
Splunk, on the other hand, doesn't seem to parse it at all, and instead recognizes generic space separated values, and key-value pairs in the whole message. This does include the structured data, but severity/facility is not decoded.

I'm hoping to find something that either runs on windows or is web based. Does such a thing exist? After installing trials for various tools of about 3 pages worth of search results, I'm willing to pay, but free would of course be nice :)

Comment: I'm using `logstash` - it combines with `elasticsearch` and `kibana`. But I wouldn't know how to get it working on Windows. `logstash` does support custom filters for log parsing though.

Comment: logstash, elasticsearch and kibana were actually painless to get to run on windows. Looks like I might indeed need a custom filter to parse the fields of our logs, but this doesn't look too hard at a first glance. Thank you!